# How to add images in your app from gallery into recyclerview in android?

Tags: android

My app contains a section where I have to load images from gallery and show them there. Please guide me how I can do that. I also want to make folders in which the photos will be placed. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(gallery,PICK_IMAGE);
```

I've tried the above code it selects the image and shows it on my app but when I restart my app the image disappears.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        imageUri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try https://www.androidexample365.com. 
You'll find libraries which are much easier and faster for your app

Comment: you don't save any information about the image you have picked from gallery. Therefore it doesn't show up next time

Answer (score 2):

```
 final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);

                Bitmap newPicture;

                BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

                // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
                bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

                newPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);


                myPicturesArrayList.add(newPicture);

                picturesAdapter = new MyPicturesAdapter(myPicturesArrayList); //Your custom adapter
                myRecyclerView.setAdapter(picturesAdapter );
```

---

Answer (score 1):

In that case you have to save the images first in your database locally or on server...and next time fetch from database

Answer (score 1):

After you load the image from gallery, save the image Uri in SharedPreferences. Next time load it directly (Get the uri from the Sharedpreference). 
For details pls refer [Android Shared preferences example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)